# XmlElementWrapper and strange values appended

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In my code I have this bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Data implements Serializable {

@XmlAttribute
private String _name;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "statuses")
@XmlElement(name="status")
    private List<Boolean> _statuses;

public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    _name = name;
}

    public List<Boolean> getStatuses() {
        return _statuses;
    }

    public void setStatuses(List<Boolean> statuses) {
        _statuses = statuses;
    }

 ....

}
```

This is the code to marshal the bean:

```
Writer w = null;
    try {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class);
        final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        w = new FileWriter("file.xml");
        m.marshal(obj, w);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { w.close();}
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

What I expect is:

```
<data name="data-test">
<statuses>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
</statuses>
...
</data>
```

but I got:

```
<data name="data-test">
<statuses>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
    <status>true</status>
</statuses>

// strange repetition
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>
<statuses>true</statuses>

// attribute as separated element
<name>data-test</name>
...
</data>
```

How can I avoid that strange kind of repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the access type isn't working.  did you try `XmlAccessType.FIELD`?  also, be sure you have correctly compiled your class and that your classpath is setup correctly (maybe you have an old class lying around from an earlier test?).

UPDATE:

can you try explicitly adding `@XmlTransient` to the getters/setters?

Comment: Yes but I get exactly the same result :(

Comment: @Randomize - added another suggestion.

Comment: adding transient on get/set I get: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions...

Comment: @Randomize - what version of java are you using and are you using the default (built in) jaxb implementation?

Comment: Yes built in version in JDK 1.6.24. I just switched to Java 7 and the problem seems gone! BTW java 6 should be got to the version 1.6.31. It looks to me a version problem at this point.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a bug in built in jaxb for JDK 1.6.24